# Is it possible to have a equation system that forms a matrix 3x3, having 2 solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a matrix 3x3 have 2 solutions? Can it be determined somehow without solving it? For other type of matrix, how do you determine the number of solutions without solving it?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer is that there will only ever be $0$ solutions, exactly $1$ solution, or infinitely many solutions (*for real or complex matrices*).  To determine how many solutions a matrix equation $Ax=b$ has, you should verify first that $b\in Im(A)$ (if $b\notin Im(A)$ then there are no solutions) and then find $dim(\ker(A))$ (if $b\in Im(A)$ and $dim(\ker(A))=0$ then exactly one solution, else infinitely many)

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

The solution to a matrix equation of the form $$Ax=b$$ represents (geometrically) the intersection of several objects called *flats*.  Flats include things like lines, planes, and $3$-spaces.  Basically "flat" things ;).

If the matrix $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, then the above equation represents $n$ flats, each of which have dimension $m-1$.  A $1$-dimensional flat is a line, a $2$-dimensional flat is a plane, etc.

Thus if $A$ is a $3\times 3$ real-valued matrix, then the matrix equation $Ax=b$ represents $3$ planes.  The solution to that equation is then the intersection of those three planes.  Three planes in $\Bbb R^3$ can have the following different arrangements in space:

[image]

Try to go through each of these and figure out how many different solutions the matrix equation representing these $5$ arrangements have.  Do any of them intersect at exactly $2$ points?  Do you think it would be possible for a set of flats in $\Bbb R^n$ to ever intersect at exactly $2$ points?

Comment: He didn't say $\mathbb R^n$.  Maybe he has a finite field...

Comment: I highly doubt it based on the question.  If I'm wrong, OP can comment here and I'll address the case of vector spaces over finite fields.